# PostgreSQL: insert string in a large object from an SQL script without relying on an external file

Tags: sql, postgresql, blob

I know it's possible to insert into a large object from a PostgreSQL script using a `lo_import()`:

```
INSERT INTO image (name, raster)
VALUES ('beautiful image', lo_import('/etc/motd'));
```

Te problem is, I'm trying to execute a script on a tightly locked up server, so I can't upload a file to it. Is it possible to insert a constant string into a large object without relying on an external file?

Comment: As long as the text in the file will fit inside of the field I don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: It's a large object, so the size won't be a problem; the question is: how do I store a string into a large object from inside a SQL script without pulling the contents from an external file? All examples I've found so far rely on an external file.

Comment: You can store up to 1 GB of text in a simple `text` or `varchar` field. Why do you need a actual large object (or `bytea`)?

Comment: It's a legacy issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the value is less than a 1GB, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO image (name, raster)
    VALUES ('beautiful image', lo_from_bytea(0,$1));
```

The `bytea` type is a bit annoying.  You may have to resort to driver-specific shenanigans to make the driver/client library understand that $1 is of type `bytea`.  For example in with Perl's DBD::Pg, you have to prepare the statement and then do something like:

```
$insert->bind_param(1, $blob, { pg_type => PG_BYTEA });
```

Comment: Mmm... interesting... so if I wanted to store some large text into a large object, maybe I could do something like: `INSERT INTO something (name, raster) VALUES ('some name', lo_from_bytea(0,'some really long text'::bytea))`

Comment: Yes.  I think it will even do the cast to bytea for you if you omit it.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, it does. Just tested it on PostgreSQL 9.6.5 and it works without the cast.